# Integers and fractions

Tags: fractions

How would I write this as an integer or a fraction in lowest terms?

$(1-\frac12)(1+\frac 12)(1-\frac13)(1+\frac13)(1-\frac14)(1+\frac14).....(1-\frac1{99})(1+\frac1{99})$

I really need to understand where to start and the process if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: [telescopy,](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy) note how the adjacent like-colored terms all cancel out of the products below

$$\rm  \left(1-\frac{1}2\right)\left(1-\frac{1}3\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{1}n\right)\ =\ \frac{1}{\color{red}2} \frac{\color{red}2}{\color{green}3} \frac{\color{green}3}{\color{blue}4} \frac{\color{blue} 4}{}\: \cdots\: \frac{}{\color{brown}{n-1}}\frac{\color{brown}{n-1}}n\ =\ \frac{1}n $$

---

$$\rm \left(1+\frac{1}2\right)\left(1+\frac{1}3\right)\cdots \left(1+\frac{1}n\right)\ =\ \frac{\color{red}3}2 \frac{\color{green}4}{\color{red}3} \frac{\color{blue}5}{\color{green}4}\frac{}{\color{blue}5}\: \cdots\: \frac{\color{brown} n}{}\frac{n+1}{\color{brown}n}\ =\ \frac{n+1}2$$

---

Hence $$\rm \prod_{k\:=\:2}^n\: \left( 1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\ =\ \frac{n+1}{2\:n} $$

Follow the above link for many more examples of telescopic proofs (additive and multiplicative).

Comment: Thanks for laying it out like this, I was able to see what numbers canceled each other out!

Answer (score 9):

Rewrite it instead as

$$\color{Green}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{1}{98}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{99}\right)}\times \color{Blue}{\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{1}{98}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{99}\right)}$$

Evaluate left and right parts separately. **Hint**: Look at how numerator and denominator cancel.

For example,

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right)=\frac{\color{DarkOrange}1}{\color{Red}2}\cdot\frac{\color{Red}2}{\color{Green}3}\cdot\frac{\color{Green}3}{\color{Blue}4}\cdot\frac{\color{Blue}4}{\color{DarkOrange}5}=\frac{1}{5}.$$

Comment: So are you saying that in (1-1/2) and (1+1/2) that the 1/2 cancels each other out?

Comment: @SNS: No, I am not saying anything about 1-1/2 in relation to 1+1/2. I am telling you to **separate** those factors so you can deal with the *minus factors* independently of the *plus factors*. In other words, we are rearranging $a_1b_1\cdots a_n b_n$ to $a_1\cdots a_n b_1\cdots b_n$.

Comment: Ok, so in the minus factors it would leave 1/99!

Comment: @SNS: Exactly! Now experiment with the plus factors and see if you can put it all together...

Comment: And in the plus factors it would leave 100/2=50

Comment: So the answer would be 50/99????

Comment: @SNS: That is the correct answer, congratulations!

Comment: Thank you so much!! I feel a weight lifted. I have been struggling with this for 2 weeks!